# JSP + taglib displaytag.sf.net , Sorting ASC and DESC are not work when click on Next Page

Tags: java, html, jsp, taglib

Good Day!,

JSP + taglib displaytag.sf.net , Sorting ASC and DESC are not work when click on Next Page, first page 10 rows, and the next page 10 rows.

example Source file:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>

    <body>
        <display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.menuForm.actorList" requestURI="/menuAction.do" pagesize="10" export="true">
            <display:column property="dessert" title="dessert" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"   />
            <display:column property="mainDish" title="main Dish" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"  />
            <display:column property="beverage" title="beverage" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"  />
        </display:table>
    </body>
```

Any Idea,

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Solutions by  override this behavior by providing a displaytag.properties file in classpath.

displaytag.properties:

sort.amount = list